# Add Custom action in Rails Admin

Tags: rails-admin

Is seem there is really poor documentation of Rails admin All I can find is this link https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action

But No where ever mention in this link how to go about using a custom action in and views for it in rails admin only install plugin that it what next. I dont have ample time to even look at the rails admin code and figure out how to do it

Here what I want is that can referred in the screenshot over [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/521882?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1343022984&Signature=fO5ajvxG%2bRNTvLjZBHrTUes1lJs=)

Answer (score 2):

Rails admin has updated their wiki but it is not in the link you have mentioned.

Instead they have placed it in the [Actions wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions) itself.

This is much more detailed and probably comprehensive.